# What is the relationship between OAuth2 and MFA

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, mailkit, multi-factor-authentication

This is my first question on the Stackoverflow. I have already read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section and I have read and read and read over the internet to find the connection between OAuth2 and MFA. Which made me more confused. When I take them separately I understand the basic concept.

Background. I am developing a windows application and using mailkit to implement the email there. When I research how to implement MFA on that, most of the answers are talking about OAuth2. That's why I really need to find an answer for this questions.

I have read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/513048/microsoft-office-365-outlook-sending-emails-using.html and https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md and many more articles to achieve my goal. They all are talking about OAuth2 not MFA.

I am sorry if my questions doesn't make much sense. Please help me to understand this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 and MFA are not related to one another directly.

OAuth 2.0 is an authorization protocol which provides a client application with the delegated access. Way of delegation is defined by [grant type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/) and based on the use case you can choose one or another. It does not tell you directly how to authenticate the end user.

For example, using classic [authorization code flow](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/) you can point the user to login page and optionally consent screen (allow / deny access to the app). An example of URL would be:

```
https://authorization-server.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=photos&state=1234zyx
```

Then it's up to authorization server how to authenticate the end user. It can be a login / password screen followed by any type of MFA.

MFA, on the other hand, stands for multi-factor authentication, meaning that there can be 2 of more factors of authentication (such as login and password pair followed by one time code, SMS or anything else).

Based on my understanding of the [OAuth2 with Exchange](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md) that you've shared, you just need to register an application on Microsoft platform in order to access Microsoft APIs for email sending. That's indeed an OAuth 2.0, but I don't see anything related to MFA there.